# BehaviorSubject continues to emit user data from old, signed out user after new user signed in?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm currently using BehaviorSubject (RxJava) to cache results from my API so subsequent loads are much faster. This works great, however, until I log out of my app. Once I log out and then log back in as a different user, for some reason, despite the request coming from a different user Id, the response is the same as the old user Id. It continues to be this way even when I log out again and back in again. It only resets when I close the app and reopen with a new sign in screen does the response data change to the current user's.

I narrowed the issue down to the Behavior Subject. Is there a way, upon signing out of the app (or prior to signin in the app), delete all the BehaviorSubjects? I allow the app to autodirect to the main page if the user has already logged in before, this isn't an issue, only when the user logs in new does the BehaviorSubject gets deleted.

My idea was have a hashmap stored somewhere that maps keys to BehaviorSubjects. Once I log out, I clear that hashmap (that way I can clear all the BehaviorSubjects everywhere in my app, not just this one).

```
Disposable disposable = getData(
            request,
            (List<Item> items) -> {
                RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mBinding.recyclerView.getAdapter();
                if (adapter instanceof ItemAdapter) {
                    ((ItemAdapter) adapter).setItems(items);
                } else {
                    adapter = ItemAdapter.getInstance(items);
                    mBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            },
            (Throwable ex) -> {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            });
```

And here is the other code:

```
public Disposable getData(SomeRequest request, Consumer<List<Item>> onNext, Consumer<Throwable> onError) {
    BehaviorSubject cacheSubject = getCache("Key");  // get BehaviorSubject stored earlier 
    if (cacheSubject == null) {
        BehaviorSubject<List<Item>> cache = BehaviorSubject.create();
        Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<List<Item>> e) -> {
                    getApi().getQuery(request)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe((Response<ResponseBody> response) -> {
                                if (response.body() != null) {
                                    ResponseBody body = response.body();
                                    if (body.getItems() != null) {
                                        List<Item> items = body.getItems();
                                        cache.onNext(items);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, (Throwable ex) -> {
                                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                                cache.onError(ex);
                            });
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(cache);
        putCache("Key", cache);  // update or create new BehaviorSubject in that map
        cacheSubject = cache;
    }
    return cacheSubject
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(onNext, onError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to clear the BehaviorSubject (because otherwise don't call onComplete on it). That is not supported but you can achieve a similar effect by having a current value that is ignored by consumers:

```
public static final Object EMPTY = new Object();
BehaviorSubject<Object> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(EMPTY);

Observable<YourType> obs = subject.filter(v -> v != EMTPY).cast(YourType.class);

obs.subscribe(System.out::println);

// send normal data
subject.onNext(1);
subject.onNext(2);

// clear the subject
subject.onNext(EMPTY);

// this should not print anything
obs.subscribe(System.out::println);
```